# Can a 16-bit microcontroller contain 32-bit microprocessor?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor

I am new to the field of embedded systems. I am wondering if 16-bit microcontroller can contain a 32-bit microprocessor. How will the data transfer take place as data busses in the microcontroller will be 16-bit wide and the microprocessor's data bus will be 32-bit wide. Please give the answer in simple words

Comment: Can you be more specific why you ask this question? It can't simultaneously be classified as 16-bit or 32-bit device. Sure a 32-bit MCU or CPU can have a 16-bit bus, the world is full with such examples.

Comment: in general when you say 16 or 32 bit micro controller you are not talking about the bus width but the micro processor architecture

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldn't make sense for a 16-bit microcontroller to contain a 32-bit microprocessor. You might have micontrollers with different bit width for their data and memory bus. But it would make no sense to refer to a microcontroller as being a "16-bit microcontroller" if their operations are done with 32 bits. You would just say it is a 32-bit microcontroller, also, even for a 32-bit microcontroller they would not implement 32 bit wide memory lines, they would have it just as wide enough to access all the memory blocks of that specific model or (maybe) to fit all model of the same family.

Comment: I will just add that in some cases it is purely opinion-based how to define the bitness of a CPU or MCU. For example the Motorola 68000 is even defined as being 16/32 bit by the manufacturer. It can be both or either one or neither depending on which aspect of it you are looking at, and arguing over which one it is won't change how it works.

Comment: consider the 68008 even!